# Custom Headers in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I have the following data model:

```
public class ListData
{
    public string Name { get; init; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Items { get; init; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

I have a ViewModel setup for the views DataContext with a public `ObservableCollection<ListData>` property also called ListData.

I want to be able to have the `Name` property as a column header within a DataGrid control, and the `Items` elements as the rows within the column.

So far I have this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ListData}"
          Grid.Row="2"
          Grid.Column="2">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Name}" Binding="{Binding Items}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

However this only displays the following:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8NDk.png)

What am I doing wrong?

This is ideally what I would like as an example:
[Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEhku.png)

Comment: Try setting the [AutoGenerateColumns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratecolumns?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) property to `False`.

Comment: @MichalDiviš, I think you're wrong, it's about creating columns dynamically, so the number of columns = ObservableCollection's Count

Comment: @MuhammadSulaiman you're right, I didn't check the goal example image and assumed the problem was about something else

Answer (score 0):

Every component or control in WPF was done for a unique reason. Thus, DataGrid has a specific template to achieve one specific goal or responsibility. If you need to change the structure of your result, you have to change the template of the DataGrid, which is not a proper way. When you try to do this kind of customization, I suggest you to use the basic and simple controls which will allow you to easily reach your goal.
Here is your Sample in few lines, using ItemsControl and ListBox.

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridCustomHeader.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListData}" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Name}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black"/>
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>

</Window>
```

Using code behind just for test (you can use the viewmodel)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace DataGridCustomHeader
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ListData> ListData { get; set; }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            ListData = new ObservableCollection<ListData>
            {
                new ListData
                {
                    Name="Letters",
                    Items = new List<string>{"A", "B", "C"}
                },
                 new ListData
                {
                    Name="Words",
                     Items = new List<string>{"Hello", "Word", ""}
                },
                  new ListData
                {
                    Name="Numbers",
                     Items = new List<string>{"1", "2", "3"}
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DataGridCustomHeader
{
    public class ListData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> Items { get; set; }
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    }
}
```